# How to get the shortest distance from a point in space to a line segment?

Tags: unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I have 2 lines and a point in space. I want to see which line the point is on. So a way to do this, is to get the distances from the point to each line and compare them. How to do that?
Also, how to get the coordinates of the intersection point of the green line and the black line?
Thanks

Diagram of what I have in mind:
[image: Diagram of what I have in mind]

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector3 X;
if( Vector3.Dot(A-B,P-A)>0 ) X = A;
else if( Vector3.Dot(B-A,P-B)>0 ) X = B;
else X = A + Vector3.Project( P-A , B-A );
float distance = X.magnitude;
```

---

[image: point and line segment]
(lines may not appear perpendicular only because this is 3d perspective view)

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PointLineSegment : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform _A = null, _B = null, _P = null;
    void OnDrawGizmos ()
    {
        if( _A==null || _B==null || _P==null ) return;

        Vector3 X, A = _A.position, B = _B.position, P = _P.position;
        if( Vector3.Dot(A-B,P-A) > 0 ) X = A;
        else if( Vector3.Dot(B-A,P-B) > 0 ) X = B;
        else X = A + Vector3.Project( P-A , B-A );
        float distance = X.magnitude;

        UnityEditor.Handles.Label( A , nameof(A) );
        UnityEditor.Handles.Label( B , nameof(B) );
        UnityEditor.Handles.Label( P , nameof(P) );
        UnityEditor.Handles.Label( X , nameof(X) );
        Gizmos.DrawLine( A , B );
        Gizmos.color = Color.cyan;
        Gizmos.DrawLine( P , X );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A little bit of thinking will be required to figure this out but it has all the information you need.

http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon. The answer must stand on it's own and any external links must be for "extra" information. That is because external links go dead all the time and if the answer heavily relies on it it will become useless.